# 期待した結果を取得できるが、 返り値のHTTP コードがint(0)となる理由は？

Tags: php, http, php-curl

下記で、curl_exec実行すると期待した結果を取得できるのですが、
curl_getinfoの結果が何れもint(0)になります。

・どういう意味ですか？
・サーバ設定が関係しているのですか？

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($hoge),
]);

curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

「curl_getinfoの結果が何れもint(0)になります」というのは、
いずれのcurl_getinfoの実行も失敗に終わっていて、False (0)が返された、という事だと思います。

```
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
```

のように、curl_getinfoの実行結果を使っていない（結果を変数に代入したり、if文などで判断したりしていない）のなら、「結果が何れもint(0)になります」とかいうのも判りようがありません。

curl_getinfoを使う気がないなら、コードに書かない。
curl_getinfoをコードに書くなら、ちゃんと使う。
中途半端なことをしていると、後始末が大変になります。(痛い目にあったことがあります)

Comment: curl_getinfoの実行結果は、curl_initからcurl_execまでのセッション期間のhttpステータスコードを返しているわけではないのでしょうか？　同じセッション期間中にcurl_getinfo()は失敗しても、curl_execが成功することはあり得る？？